# Im currently learning how to use Tensorflow and is following the tutorial. I have created the graph but unable to view it

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, tensorboard

I followed the instruction to run the command "tensorbard --logdir ." and there are no graph at the Tensorboard graph page and i get these errors

```
    Exception in thread Reloader:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\imkha\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "c:\users\imkha\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "c:\users\imkha\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\backend\application.py", line 350, in _reload_forever
    reload_multiplexer(multiplexer, path_to_run)
  File "c:\users\imkha\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\backend\application.py", line 322, in reload_multiplexer
    multiplexer.AddRunsFromDirectory(path, name)
  File "c:\users\imkha\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\backend\event_processing\plugin_event_multiplexer.py", line 175, in AddRunsFromDirectory
    for subdir in GetLogdirSubdirectories(path):
  File "c:\users\imkha\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\backend\event_processing\plugin_event_multiplexer.py", line 445, in <genexpr>
    subdir
  File "c:\users\imkha\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\backend\event_processing\io_wrapper.py", line 50, in ListRecursively
    for dir_path, _, filenames in tf.gfile.Walk(top):
  File "c:\users\imkha\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 518, in walk
    for subitem in walk(os.path.join(top, subdir), in_order):
  File "c:\users\imkha\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 518, in walk
    for subitem in walk(os.path.join(top, subdir), in_order):
  File "c:\users\imkha\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 518, in walk
    for subitem in walk(os.path.join(top, subdir), in_order):
  File "c:\users\imkha\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 499, in walk
    listing = list_directory(top)
  File "c:\users\imkha\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 478, in list_directory
    compat.as_bytes(dirname), status)
  File "c:\users\imkha\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py", line 473, in __exit__
    c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnknownError: FindFirstFile failed for: C:\Users\imkha\AppData\Local\Application Data : Access is denied.
; Input/output error
```

i have tried the debugging steps provided on the page but it did not seem to work. Thank you in advance. (OS:Windows 10)

Comment: `tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnknownError: FindFirstFile failed for: C:\Users\imkha\AppData\Local\Application Data : Access is denied.` It seems your program is trying to access a file/folder it's not allowed to access.

Comment: Try running the cmd in administrator mode

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and, as Rajat suggested, I used the `cmd` in administrator mode.

Worked like a charm.